# Flume agent producing multiple .tmp files when data is sent in succession

Tags: apache-kafka, cloudera, flume

I have a flume agent running in CDH 5.8.3. It creates multiple .tmp files when writing to hdfs if more than 3 valid files are sent. There is an interceptor that routes valid xmls to appropriate topic before the hdfs sink. This agent is using flafka. Interceptor and kafka are working correctly.

```
agent.sinks.hdfs_valid.channel=valid_channel
agent.sinks.hdfs_valid.type=hdfs
agent.sinks.hdfs_valid.writeFormat=Text
agent.sinks.hdfs_valid.hdfs.fileType=DataStream
agent.sinks.hdfs_valid.hdfs.filePrefix=event
agent.sinks.hdfs_valid.hdfs.fileSuffix=.xml
agent.sinks.hdfs_valid.hdfs.path=locationoffile/%{time}
agent.sinks.hdfs_valid.hdfs.idleTimeout=900
agent.sinks.hdfs_valid.hdfs.rollInterval=3600
agent.sinks.hdfs_valid.hdfs.kerberosPrincipal=authentication@example.com
agent.sinks.hdfs_valid.hdfs.kerberosKeytab=locationofkeytab
agent.sinks.hdfs_valid.hdfs.rollSize=0
agent.sinks.hdfs_valid.hdfs.rollCount=0
agent.sinks.hdfs_valid.hdfs.callTimeout=100000
```

Answer (score 0):

Okay so interesting enough. Our Kafka partitions was set to 20. When flume consumes from it. The first 10 partitions are consuming from one ip and it opens a .tmp. The second 10 partitions are consuming from another ip and it opens a second .tmp. This appears to be an internal function of flume. All data arrived correctly despite having two .tmp opened.